# value of cell in a table where jQuery contextMenu was clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Consider the following [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a00o4p87/14/).

It uses [jQuery contextMenu](http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html) to display a right-click context menu as added to the table body.

```
<table border="1">
  <tbody class="context-menu-one">
    <tr>
      <td>R1C1</td>
      <td>R1C2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>R2C1</td>
      <td>R1C2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.context-menu-one',
        callback: function(key, options) {
            var clickedKey= key;
            //How to get the Value of the clicked cell here ?
            var  m = $(options.$trigger).text();
            window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
        },
        items: {
            "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
            "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
        }
    });

    $('.context-menu-one').on('click', function(e){
        console.log('clicked', this);
    })
});
```

How do i get the value of the cell where the context menu is invoked ?

For example, invoking of context menu by clicking in the 1st row, 1 column of the table should give me the value `R1C1`.

Comment: I don't see the context menu code in the fiddle. Did you post the correct link?

Comment: am sorry, I hadn't saved the changes. It should now show up

Comment: Take a look at this example in the documentation: http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo/on-dom-element.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make the `selector:` option select the table cells. Then `this` in the callback will be the cell that you clicked on.

```
$(function() {
    $(".context-menu-one").contextMenu({
        selector: 'td',
        callback: function(key, options) {
            var content = $(this).text();
            alert("You clicked on: " + content);
        },
        items: {
            "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
            "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
        }
    });
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/a00o4p87/17/)

Comment: Nice shot. I have downloaded the plugin and i was almost there. But as always you are to fast for me. up voted :)

Answer (score 0):

This will get the text inside the clicked td element:

```
$('.context-menu-one td').on('click', function(e){
     console.log($(this).text());
 })
```

Comment: But how does he do that from one of the options in the context menu? E.g. if he clicks on "Edit", he wants to be able to edit the contents.

Comment: Woeps @Barmar you are right. But I can not emulate the contest menu on my computer so I have to look around for this. If in the meanwhile nobody has the answer he is looking for than (maybe) I can update this. Thank you for point me to this. As always I am to impulsive.